# How can I show the application name in the panel?

Tags: 11.10, appmenu, gnome-fallback

I'm using GNOME Fallback Mode with Indicator applets in the panel, since they've recently been ported to GNOME 3. I installed the `indicator-appmenu` package and I'm using it on the GNOME Panel. However, it doesn't show the application name like it does in Unity. How can I make it show the name of the application?

Here's a screenshot. I'd like it to say the application name between the main menu and the appmenu.
[image]

Comment: Screenshot please

Comment: @AboobackerMk Added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your looking for this [Window Applets](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/window-applets-finally-available-for.html)

Taken from linked page:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-window-applets
```

then you need to open the add to panel dialog, presumably by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ right click(or alt+super, right click) and then select Window Title and add.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I'll give you the 50 rep when I can (in about 7 hours)